# where to add override operator << for enums

Tags: c++, enums

I use visual studio in my sln exist some projects: Common, Trader

In Common I have class Print in namespace Helper

```
namespace Helper{
    template<T>
    class Print{
        template<T>
        static PrintEnum(std::ostream &os, const std::string& prefix,const T& val){
            os << prefix << ":" << val;
        }
    };
}
```

and in project Trader exist some enums in file Typedef.h like below:

```
namespace Market{
    enum Coin{USD,JPY,EUR};
}
```

and exist function print in class Platform like below:

```
namespace Market{

    void Platform::PrintTheBest(std::ostream &os){
        Coin best = USD;
        Helper::Print::PrintEnum(os, std::string("Best"),best);
    }
}
```

I want to override << for print enum Coin like below:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& , const Coin& coin){
 .....
}
```

But I dont know where to add the operator code.

In Common project coin enum  doesn't exist and if I add the operator in Trader project I get link error unresolve external

Comment: Don’t write C++ code like that, it’s a Java-ism. Your `static` member functions should be functions outside classes. That would also take care of your problem of where to define the streaming operator.

Comment: Is your operator definition inside namespace Market? Re. the previous comment: if static methods belong to a class, they should be defined in that class, to code in the common object-oriented way (except for operators, which by common convention are defined in the way herzl does). But it's up to the preferences of the coder really.

Comment: Also, if you're adding it in the .h, it should be inline.

Answer (score 0):

When implementing an operator for a user defined type you need to implement it in a way where ADL (argument dependent look-up) can find them. ADL finds functions in the namespaces associated with the function arguments. Since the only namespace involved with the output operator are namespace `std` and the namespace where the user-defined type is defined. Since you are not allowed to add anything to namespace `std` the namespace of the user-defined type is the only option.